# Details view and field edit authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to utilize a details view and provide the edit feature for a few levels of user authorization. Basically level 1 users cannot update a predefined set of fields but level 2 users can update these fields. I had tried simply setting the field to `visible=false` when defining the `EditTemplate` and then in the `DataBind` I would test for authorization and make it `visible=true` if the user had privileges to update the field (see code example below). Worked like a charm, except I noticed that when level 1 users update the fields they are allowed to update, the `visible=false` fields would be set to `null` (overwritten) in the database. So, been trying various options not to have to duplicate the views etc.

code snippet:
aspx....

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Level %>" 
    SortExpression="LevelId">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="LevelList" runat="server" 
                DataTextField="LevelDesc" DataValueField="LevelId">
             </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Level1 %>" 
    SortExpression="Level1Date" Visible="false" >
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Level1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                Bind("Level1Date", "{0:d}") %>'  />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date (m/d/y)" 
                ControlToValidate="Level1" Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
                Type="Date" Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:CompareValidator>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Level2 %>" 
       SortExpression="Level2Date" Visible="false" >
       <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="Level2" runat="server" Text='<%# 
               Bind("Level2Date", "{0:d}") %>'  />
           <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 
               ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date (m/d/y)" 
               ControlToValidate="Level2" Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
               Type="Date" Display="Dynamic">
           </asp:CompareValidator>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Level4 %>" 
       SortExpression="Level4Date" Visible="false" >
       <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="Level4" runat="server" Text='<%# 
               Bind("Level4Date", "{0:d}") %>'  />
 </Fields>
```

aspx.cs SNIPPET

```
<name>_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
.
.
.
if (User.IsInRole("yyy") || User.IsInRole("xxx))
{
    OfficialProfileInfo.Fields[2].Visible = true;
    OfficialProfileInfo.Fields[3].Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the DataKeyNames property for the automatic updating, deleting, and inserting features of the DetailsView control to work.

While updating if some fields should not change, you can put them in the key.

```
if (User.IsInRole("yyy") || User.IsInRole("xxx))
{
    OfficialProfileInfo.Fields[2].Visible = true;
    OfficialProfileInfo.Fields[3].Visible = true;
}
else
{
    OfficialProfileInfo.DataKeyNames = "Level4Date"
}
```

**Note:** DataKeyNames is a comma-seperated list of field names/

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use try them I get an error stating "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'"